# Android - ActionBar - hide overflow menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I want to hide this overflow menu:
     [a busy cat http://cdn.intertech.com/PostingImages/Android-Action-Bar-from-the-Options-Menu_E1C5/image_7.png](http://cdn.intertech.com/PostingImages/Android-Action-Bar-from-the-Options-Menu_E1C5/image_7.png)

I can hide it, when I set targetSdkVersion="14". But I don't want that. I don't want to give a target version.

I also tried this here (/res/values/styles.xml):

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Not working. I see the 3 dots menu.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried `android:showAsAction="never"` in the menu's xml file?

Comment: I want to hide that, because the app crashes when I click on that button. I don't know why? Maybe, the reason for that is the new appcompat?

Comment: Havr you put below line in Activity "android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen". IT will make sure that you will not get TitleBar

Comment: What i am understanding from Image 3 dots is responsible for showing Menu option and there could be chances that your layout for XML is not inflated by system. Reason could be different, can you please share the logs that you are getting while you pressed.

Comment: I tried the Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen. But I got this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I don't know why, but no more app crashing. Hmm.